# Computing a Closed Form for an Infinite Series Involving ArcSins

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, trigonometric-series

Specifically, I would like compute the following in closed form for some $\alpha \in [0,1]$

$$ \sum_{\ell \geq 1} \arcsin( \alpha^\ell ) \left( 1 + 2 \alpha^{2\ell} \right) \,. 
$$

I have tried using the Taylor expansion for $\arcsin$ and summing over the geometric series over $\ell$, it just looks more complicated

$$ \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{ (2k)! }{ 2^{2k} (k!)^2 (2k+1) } \left( \frac{ \alpha^{2k+1} }{ 1 - \alpha^{2k+1} } + \frac{ 2 \alpha^{2k+3} }{ 1 - \alpha^{2k+3} } \right) \,, 
$$

and I don't see any further simplifications beyond this point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have reason to suspect a closed form exists?

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately no, it's just purely wishful thinking. I realized that I should not be so optimistic after seeing all the other unanswered questions under the "tignometric-series" tag.